# Popup Window is automatically closing after update Browser (IE11 , chrome (newest version)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am working on a application , where an error has occured after I updated my browsers to the newest version. For example the error doesnt occur if I am using IE 10, with IE 11 the error/bug it is not occuring. I will try the error so exactly as possible. If you cannot follow me, you can ask me explicit questions.
The bug is produced by javascript.

Main Description: I have a button, if it is clicked a popup fenster is opened dynamically with JQuery:

```
jQuery(html.join('')).dialog(
            {
                modal : true,
                width : 650,
                height : 500,
                autoOpen : true,
                closeOnEscape : true,
                draggable : true,
                resizable : false,
                buttons : [
                /*
                 * { text: alerts_GetMessageText(ghAlertsDetailsMessages,
                 * 'Alerts.AlertDetails.Reason.Dialog.Cancel') ,click:
                 * function() { jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" ); }
                 * ,classes: 'ButtonDialogLeft' },
                 */
                {
                    text : alerts_GetMessageText(ghAlertsDetailsMessages,
                            'Alerts.AlertDetails.Reason.Dialog.OK'),
                    click : alerts_Details_CloseReasonDialog,
                    classes : 'ButtonDialogRight'
                } ]
            });
```

The bug is, that the Popup-Window is closed immediately after it is shown. I suppose the cause is that the current is redirected to the same current page. So I am landing on the same page with closed popup-window.

I know it is not easy to explain the point, but what is irritating me, that no errors are shown in the console.

The popup window is filled by calling:

```
goMyAlertsCommandQueue.addAjaxCall({
        type : "GET",
        url : './showAlertsAlertReasonAjax.do',
        dataType : "html",
        data : ({
            AjaxAction : 'data',
            AlertId : alertId
        })
    }, alerts_Details_OpenReasonDialogReady);
    goMyAlertsCommandQueue.run();
```

alerts_Details_OpenReasonDialogReady is looking like:

```
function alerts_Details_OpenReasonDialogReady(poHtml) {
// Button ausrichten
/*
 * jQuery("button[classes='ButtonDialogLeft']",
 * jQuery(this).parent()).css("float","left");
 */
jQuery("button[classes='ButtonDialogRight']", jQuery(this).parent()).css(
        "float", "right");

// show dialog data
jQuery("#ReasonDialog div").remove();
jQuery("#ReasonDialog").append(poHtml);

// 'Close'-Button ausblenden
jQuery(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").show();

dropdownList();
firstTime = false;
```

}

some time later this function jquery-ui:

```
_delay: function( handler, delay ) {
    function handlerProxy() {
        return ( typeof handler === "string" ? instance[ handler ] : handler )
            .apply( instance, arguments );
    }
    var instance = this;
    return setTimeout( handlerProxy, delay || 0 );
},
```

After return ( typeof handler === "string" ? instance[ handler ] : handler )
                .apply( instance, arguments );  is being executed, the page is redirected to the current page and the popup is disappearing. No errors are shown in the console. So I cannot recognize what causes the error. If u have any questions so please ask, I am grateful for any help.

Edit: @halcyon

```
function alerts_Details_OpenReasonDialog() {
var alertId = jQuery(this).attr("alertId");

if (firstTime) {
    // 
    //jQuery("#ReasonDialog").dialog('destroy');
    jQuery("#ReasonDialog").remove();

    var html = [];
    var i = -1;

    html[++i] = "<div class='cReasonDialog' id='ReasonDialog' title='"
            + alerts_GetMessageText(ghAlertsDetailsMessages,
                    'Alerts.AlertDetails.Reason.Dialog.Title') + "'>";
    html[++i] = "<div style='margin-top:50px; text-align:center;'>"
            + alerts_GetMessageText(ghAlertsDetailsMessages,
                    'Alerts.AlertDetails.Reason.Dialog.LoadingData')
            + "</div>";
    html[++i] = "<div style='margin-top:25px; text-align:center;'><img src='./reportingErgon/img/icon_loading.gif' alt='"
            + alerts_GetMessageText(ghAlertsDetailsMessages,
                    'Alerts.AlertDetails.Reason.Dialog.LoadingData')
            + "' /></div>";
    html[++i] = "</div>";
    jQuery(html.join('')).dialog(
            {
                modal : true,
                width : 650,
                height : 500,
                autoOpen : true,
                closeOnEscape : true,
                draggable : true,
                resizable : false,
                buttons : [
                /*
                 * { text: alerts_GetMessageText(ghAlertsDetailsMessages,
                 * 'Alerts.AlertDetails.Reason.Dialog.Cancel') ,click:
                 * function() { jQuery( this ).dialog( "close" ); }
                 * ,classes: 'ButtonDialogLeft' },
                 */
                {
                    text : alerts_GetMessageText(ghAlertsDetailsMessages,
                            'Alerts.AlertDetails.Reason.Dialog.OK'),
                    click : alerts_Details_CloseReasonDialog,
                    classes : 'ButtonDialogRight'
                } ]
            });

    goMyAlertsCommandQueue.reset();
    goMyAlertsCommandQueue.addAjaxCall({
        type : "GET",
        url : './showAlertsAlertReasonAjax.do',
        dataType : "html",
        data : ({
            AjaxAction : 'data',
            AlertId : alertId
        })
    }, alerts_Details_OpenReasonDialogReady);
    goMyAlertsCommandQueue.run();
    firstTime = false;
} else {
    jQuery("#dropdown1 input").val("");
    jQuery("#FilterText").val("");
    jQuery("#FilterValue").val("");
    jQuery("input[name=Rating]:checked").attr("checked", false);
    jQuery(".cErrorMessage").text("");
    jQuery("#ReasonDialog").dialog('open');
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us the code that initiates the opening of the dialog? It might be a missing `preventDefault` in a link or something similar.

Comment: jQuery("#OpenReasonButton").click(alerts_Details_OpenReasonDialog);

Comment: What is `#OpenReasonButton`? And what is the implementation of `alerts_Details_OpenReasonDialog`?

Comment: No it is the id of the button, the button is associated with the function above.

Comment: @Halcyon see above, i Put the whole code.

Comment: Can you also put the HTML of the button and whatever surrounds it?

Comment: <button id="OpenReasonButton" class="cButton" value="Reason"
            title="Edit reason"
            alertId="86522"
            >
            <span>Reason</span>
            <img src="_resources/css/core/img/edit.gif"
             alt="Edit reason" />
           </button>

Comment: Still need more information buddy .. specifically, is the button in a form?

Comment: @Halcyon no bro . the button isnt surrouned by <form> </form>. the POST action works over Ajax, see 2nd code block in my post.

Comment: Then I don't know why you're getting a redirect.

Comment: the button should have the attribute type='button' . That solved the problem -.-